# Test results shown before it executes - Cucumber/Angular

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber, bdd

I am new to cucumber. My tests results are shown before it executes. It shows all passed even though the browser is still loading.

Below is my *page.js

```js
var CalculatorPage = function() {
    //const {setDefaultTimeout} = require('cucumber');
    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('');
    };
```

Below is my steps.js file

```js
this.Given(/^The LoginPage is open$/, function () {
    this.page.get();
});
```

Comment: Do you do any assertions in your code? If there are no assertions, so no checks to see if something succeeded or failed, by default it will be counted as succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because JavaScript gets executed in an asynchronous manner. To make it synchronous we need to take advantage of promise.

```
var CalculatorPage = function() {
    //const {setDefaultTimeout} = require('cucumber');
    this.get = function() {
       return browser.get('');
    };

this.Given(/^The LoginPage is open$/, function (done) {
    this.page.get().then(function(){
        done()
    });
});
```